# Just trying to install/configure symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've just download a symfony2 (sf 2.0.12) with vendors, and when i go to
http://foo.localhost/config.php I get this message:

```
Welcome! Welcome to your new Symfony project. This script will guide you through the basic configuration of your project. You can also do the same by editing the ‘app/config/ parameters.ini’ file directly.
- Configure your Symfony Application online
- Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page
- Re-check configuration
```

Then I click "Configure your Symfony.." And i get this:

> InvalidConfigurationException: The child node "db_driver" at path
>   "fos_user" must be configured.

Is the same for you?

**EDIT**:

Besides, there isn't anything about the FOSUserBundle in appKernel or autoload files, nor in vendor folder. 
Anyway, I added this lines below to app/config/config.yml file:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
```

but the error is the same.

Comment: I just brought down a fresh copy of sf 2.0.12 and had no fos issues at all.  Maybe foo.localhost is not pointing to where you think it is?  Or maybe you had stuff left over from a previous install?   Maybe you tried doing some of the bin install stuff?

Comment: yes, foo.localhost was pointing to another project..

Comment: I had the same issue. I tried running an app/console command and it gave me the error you got. I updated my config.yml and got the same error. Then I remembered that console commands are run in the dev environment by default, so i updated my config_dev.yml and it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case anyone else needs this...

I had to run "composer update" on my Symfony installation without FOSUserBundle first. Then do it again with FOSUserBundle added to my composer.json file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to install the FOSUserBundle at the same time as your Symfony2 install.

Either remove the bundle before installing or configure the missing keys it is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
```

You must specify your `User` entity.
For example:

```
user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: see step5 https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md